# jQuery change() executes when reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I dont know why, but with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#errorTitle").change(getErrors());

        function getErrors(){
            console.log($(".nombre").val()+"/"+$(".email").val());

            if($("#nombre").val() === "" || $("#nombre").val() === "undefined"){
                $("#nombre").addClass("error");
            }else{
                $("#nombre").removeClass("error");
            }

            if($("#email").val() !== "" && $("#email").val() !== "undefined"){
                $("#email").removeClass("error")
            }else{
                $("#email").addClass("error");
            }
        }
    });
```

The function executes before I change anything, and if I try with the click() event it happens exactly the same. I´m just trying to change the background color with the most simple way of validation to change the error at my wish.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post"  id="contact">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nombre*</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="NAME" placeholder="Nombre y Apellidos">
                 </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email*</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="@">
                 </div>

                 <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="aviso_legal"> <p>He leído y acepto la <a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="../politica_es.html">política de privacidad</a></p>
                </label>
                </div>

                <p id="errorTitle"><?=$error?></p>

                <button type="submit" class="enviar">ENVIAR</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: remove bracket $("#errorTitle").change(getErrors);

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#errorTitle").change(getErrors());
```

You're calling `getErrors` and passing the result to `.change`. Since `getErrors()` returns nothing this code is equivalent to:

```
getErrors();
$("#errorTitle").change(undefined);
```

---

You probably intended:

```
$("#errorTitle").change(getErrors); // no ()
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be

```
$("#errorTitle").change(getErrors);
```

Adding the `()` to a function will execute it instantly (used to return a value for example)

```
var something = getSomethingBack(); // calls function
var something = getSomethingBack; // assigns function to variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a function to handler change event like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#errorTitle").change(function(){getErrors();});
}

function getErrors(){
console.log($(".nombre").val()+"/"+$(".email").val());

   if($("#nombre").val() === "" || $("#nombre").val() === "undefined"){
      $("#nombre").addClass("error");
   }else{
      $("#nombre").removeClass("error");
   }
   if($("#email").val() !== "" && $("#email").val() !== "undefined"){
     $("#email").removeClass("error")
   }else{
     $("#email").addClass("error");
   }
}
</script>
```

Your code is colling your function in each `$(document).ready` fucntion. You can also change your `$("#errorTitle").change(getErrors());` for `$("#errorTitle").change(getErrors);`